# System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory with permissions for only this current user?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, filesystems, system.io.directory

I want the asp application to create a folder that has access only to the account the application was running with (i.e. asp account?)

I actually wanna use [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h4z99zb.aspx), but I don't know how to use the "Computer\CurrentAccount" dynamically.

I want to get the current working account.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the directory example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.directorysecurity.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an example of creating a `DirectorySecurity` instance and adding an ACE for a named user [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.security.accesscontrol.directorysecurity) (but use the default constructor to start with an empty ACL).

To get the SID of the account there are two possibilities (these need testing):

The first approach is to rely on the owner of the process being the owner of the directory. This is likely to break if doing impersonation (e.g. under Windows Authentication to have the client's identity used for access control to filesystem content):

```
var ds = new DirectorySecurity();
var sid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.CreatorOwnerSid, null)
var ace = new FileSystemAccessRule(sid,
                                   FileSystemRights.FullControl,
                                   AccessControlType.Allow);
ds.AddAccessRule(ace);
```

The second approach to to get the process owner from the process Token, this will require P/Invoke. This includes an example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/processownersid.aspx, once you have the SID create a SecurityIdentifier instance for it and follow the above to create the ACL.

Comment: I want the "Computer\User" to be dynamic.

Comment: @Shimmy: I thought you might :-) ... expanding.

Comment: Oh. sorry for bothering, I wanna restrict all other user as well, can you please tell me how i could do that?

Comment: Restrict to what? An ACL with a single ACE will provide no access to anyone else.